# Preventing CSRF and XSRF Attacks for jQuery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, http-post, csrf

I was recently hit by a simple CSRF attack and realized a lot of my ajax scripts are open. These are accessed on my site with $.post().

Is there a way to automatically add a PHP token to all of these or do I need to go through and do it all one-by-one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using bwoebi's answer, I found a slightly better solution. jQuery has a built in setup function for ajax.

```
<script>var token ="<?= $_SESSION['token'] ?>";</script>
<script>
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        token: token
    }
});
</script>
```

This will add your token to every jQuery request!

Answer (score 1):

An idea would be to replace your `$.post` function:

```
jQuery["post"] = function (url, data, callback, type) {
    data["token"] = token; // where token is a global variable
    // you write in a <script> 'var token = <?php echo $_SESSION["token"]; ?>;'
    return jQuery.ajax({ // copied from the jQuery code
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: type,
        data: data,
        success: callback
    });
};
```

So you only have to add this little code after including the jq-lib.

Comment: Nice! Can I just append this to my jQuery lib or should I make a new file?

Comment: I'd write it in a new file so that it won't be lost on an update of the lib.

Comment: Okay, just found that some of my code uses the traditional `$.ajax({type: "POST",` code. Is there a way to rewrite this as well?